# How to troubleshoot the DNS

Tags: dns

I have a small network of window server 2003 and window XP in virtual box both are virtual machine. I configured the DNS and give correct result when I type the " nslookup " command in server 2003 but when I type the command in XP it give the error " Unknown server" and due to this I Can't join the XP machine in the server .
 So how I troubleshoot this problem,to join the XP machine in 2003 server,please help

Comment: How is the network configured.  We need more info to help.

Comment: What is your IP configuration of the server and the client? We need more info to answer you better...

Answer (score 1):

This might help: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Looks up DNS server in your settings for all the connections. Ping/TraceRt those servers. See which one fails.

Comment: I already checked the ping and trace route they worked well but nslookup from the xp give the error " Unknown server" due to this xp does not join in the server